# robotframework Page Should Contain Textfield variable with random input

Tags: robotframework

robotframework

I used this code:

```
Page Should Contain Textfield    xpath: //*[contains(text(), "${date}")]
```

But that searches literally (Dutch: letterlijk)

The actual content could be:

value-example1${date}value-example2

So there can be some text in front and some text after the variable...

I tried this but that didn't work

```
Page Should Contain Textfield    xpath: //*[contains(text(), "*${date}"*)]
```

so * before the ${date}  and * after the ${date} ..... (but that doesn't work)

Answer (score 3):

The reason `xpath: //*[contains(text(), "*${date}"*)]` didn't work is because xpath will look for text with literal asterisks. You don't need the asterisks, `contains` takes care of that because it looks for your requested string anywhere in the element's text.

Here is an example using `contains`. First, save the following to /tmp/example.html:

```
<html><body>
<div><h1>Some text, January 1, 2020, and more text </h1>
</body></html>
```

Next, save this to example.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary

Suite Setup     open browser  ${URL}  ${BROWSER}
Suite Teardown  Close all browsers

*** Variables ***
${URL}      file:///tmp/example.html
${BROWSER}  chrome
${date}     January 1, 2020

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Page should contain element  xpath://*[contains(text(), "${date}")]
```

When you run this test with robot, it should pass because the element contains the string stored in `${date}`.